# I need to merge sort or quick sort my string in option b using c#.net

Tags: c#

here are my codes i don't know how to enable the quick sort or merge sort using this code.

i got red lines in case b on foreach and userInput.
but if i use string[] on my userInput my Console.Readline() will be red line and also the ToCharArray. how will i fix it?

i would like to know why isn't it working and help me to recode a better one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SortString
{
    class SortStringCategory
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("Enter a string: ");

            String userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            char response;

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Choose between the two sorting strategies:");
                Console.WriteLine("\ta) - Bubble Sort");
                Console.WriteLine("\tb) - Quick Sort");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Your option: ");

                {
                    response = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                switch (response.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    case "a":

                        char temp;
                        char[] charStr = userInput.ToCharArray();
                        for (int i = 1; i < charStr.Length; i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < charStr.Length - 1; j++)
                            {
                                if (charStr[j] > charStr[j + 1])
                                {
                                    temp = charStr[j];
                                    charStr[j] = charStr[j + 1];
                                    charStr[j + 1] = temp;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        Console.Write("Bubble Sort: ");
                        Console.Write(charStr);
                        break;


                    case "b":

                        quicksort(userInput, 0, userInput.Length - 1);
                        foreach (string s in userInput)
                        {
                            Console.Write(s + " ");
                        }
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        break;


                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer. Please enter a valid option.");
                        response = '\0';
                        break;
                }

            } while (response == '\0');

        }

        static int partition(string[] userInput, int start, int end)
        {
            int pivot = end;
            int i = start, j = end;
            string temp;
            while (i < j)
            {
                while (i < end && string.Compare(userInput[i], userInput[pivot]) < 0)
                    i++;
                while (j > start && string.Compare(userInput[j], userInput[pivot]) > 0)
                    j--;

                if (i < j)
                {
                    temp = userInput[i];
                    userInput[i] = userInput[j];
                    userInput[j] = temp;
                }
            }
            temp = userInput[pivot];
            userInput[pivot] = userInput[j];
            userInput[j] = temp;
            return j;
        }

        static void quicksort(string[] userInput, int start, int end)
        {
            if (start < end)
            {
                int pivotIndex = partition(userInput, start, end);
                quicksort(userInput, start, pivotIndex - 1);
                quicksort(userInput, pivotIndex + 1, end);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Red lines means compiler errors. Which errors you get and at which lines?

Comment: I rolled your edit back to restore the question text.  If you have solved the issue independently of the answer provided you can also provide your own answer so that future readers can benefit from the solution.

Answer (score 2):

So your methods will need to take a `char[]`

```
static int partition(char[] userInput, int start, int end)

static void quicksort(char[] userInput, int start, int end)
```

You will need to give them a `char[]`

```
// this is needed to have copy of the mutated array
var charArray = userInput.ToCharArray();
quicksort(charArray, 0, userInput.Length - 1);
```

You will need to change the for loop to char in case b

```
foreach (char s in charArray)
```

Your `temp` variable in `partition` will need to be a `char`

```
char temp;
```

And instead of `string.Compare` you can just use greater than or less than

```
while (i < end && userInput[i] < userInput[pivot])
      i++;
while (j > start && userInput[j] > userInput[pivot])
      j--;
```

This disregards any other problem in your code, and only focuses on getting this to compile with a char array

Comment: i did everything you said but i still have red line in my foreach on case b and when i change the foreach (string s in userInput) to foreach (char s in userInput) the red line will vanished but when i run my program and choose b it doesn't return any value at all. help me.

Comment: @BugsBunny you need to learn how to debug your application with the step debugger. Double check each of my edits, break point case b, and step through the code and rationalize what it is meant to do, and look at what it is doing. Note i did not test this, this was only to help you move foward