# How to sort user input and separate it by spaces?

Tags: c#

**Can somebody help me to separate the user input by space so my program can sort it by spaces**

*I don't know how to separate the user input by space how will I do that?
can anyone help me with this?*

*and also if you have a suggestion in improving it please do so. thank you so much!*

***Here is the output of my program:***

Enter a string: 10 42 a ds 1 sfa 422 d w

Choose between the two sorting strategies:

a) - Bubble Sort

b) - Quick Sort

Your option: a

Bubble Sort:  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  , 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, a, a, d, d, f, s, s, w,

***I want ito be like this:***

Enter a string: 10 42 a ds 1 sfa 422 d w

Choose between the two sorting strategies:

a) - Bubble Sort

b) - Quick Sort

Your option: a

Bubble Sort: 1, 10, 42, 422, a, d, ds, sfa, w

**I am a newbie, please help me.**

**Here are my code:**

```
using System;

namespace SortStrategyPattern
{
    class Context
    {
        public static string userInput;

        private IStrategy _strategy;

        public Context()
        {}

        public Context(IStrategy strategy)
        {
            this._strategy = strategy;
        }

        public void SetStrategy(IStrategy strategy)
        {
            this._strategy = strategy;
        }

        class Program
        {

            static void Main(string[] args)
            {

                var context = new Context();
                context.UserInput();


            }
        }

        public void UserInput()
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a string: ");

            userInput = Console.ReadLine();

            char response;
            var context = new Context();
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Choose between the two sorting strategies:");
                Console.WriteLine("\ta) - Bubble Sort");
                Console.WriteLine("\tb) - Quick Sort");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("Your option: ");

                {
                    response = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                Console.WriteLine();

                switch (response.ToString().ToLower())
                {
                    case "a":
                        BubbleSort OutputA = new BubbleSort();
                        OutputA.Implementation(userInput);
                        break;


                    case "b":
                        QuickSort OutputB = new QuickSort();
                        OutputB.Implementation(userInput);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer. Please enter a valid option.");
                        response = '\0';
                        break;
                }

            } while (response == '\0');

        }

        public interface IStrategy
        {
            object Implementation(string useInput);
        }

        class BubbleSort : IStrategy
        {
            public object Implementation(string userInput)
            {
                char temp;
                char[] charStr = userInput.ToCharArray();
                for (int x = 1; x < charStr.Length; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < charStr.Length - 1; y++)
                    {
                        if (charStr[y] > charStr[y + 1])
                        {
                            temp = charStr[y];
                            charStr[y] = charStr[y + 1];
                            charStr[y + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.Write("Bubble Sort: ");
                foreach (char input in charStr)
                {
                    Console.Write(input + ", ");
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }

        class QuickSort : IStrategy
        {
            public object Implementation(string userInput)
            {
                var charArray = userInput.ToCharArray();
                quicksort(charArray, 0, userInput.Length);

                Console.Write("Quick Sort: ");
                foreach (char uinput in charArray)
                {
                    Console.Write(uinput + ", ");
                }
                return 0;
            }

            static void quicksort(char[] userInput, int start, int end)
            {
                if (start < end)
                {
                    int pivotIndex = partition(userInput, start, end);
                    quicksort(userInput, start, pivotIndex);
                    quicksort(userInput, pivotIndex + 1, end);
                }
            }

            static void swap(char[] userInput, int i, int j)
            {
                char temp = userInput[i];
                userInput[i] = userInput[j];
                userInput[j] = temp;
            }

            static int partition(char[] userInput, int start, int end)
            {
                int pivotIndex = userInput[start];
                int swapIndex = start;
                for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++)
                {
                    if (userInput[i] < pivotIndex)
                    {
                        swapIndex++;
                        swap(userInput, i, swapIndex);
                    }
                }
                swap(userInput, start, swapIndex);
                return swapIndex;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This question is getting ask multiple times a day, consider talking to other people in your class, you are all having similar issues and asking substandard questions. Please read [ask]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66081969/how-will-i-fix-my-strategy-pattern-code-help-me/66082898#66082898

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66060006/i-need-to-merge-sort-or-quick-sort-my-string-in-option-b-using-c-net/66060116#66060116

Comment: @00110001 please help me with my problem. it's different from what you forwarded me. thank you in advance. 

Comment: Your sort methods will need to take a string array `string[]`, and you will need to use `string.Compare`. The all you would need to do is split the user input using `string.Split`

Comment: @00110001 i already done that but my OutputA.Implementation(userInput); in cae a ang b become red and if i fix it by adding [0] to the code like OutputA.Implementation(userInput[0]); it will not return all the user input just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code with a slight change. Both searches return the desired result. *Do not define classes together. It reduces the readability of the program.*

> **Program class**

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var context = new Context();
      context.UserInput();
   }
}
```

> **Context class**

```
class Context
{
  public static string userInput;
  private IStrategy _strategy;
  public void UserInput()
  {
     while(true)
     {
        Console.Write("Enter a string: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        char response;
        do
        {
           Console.WriteLine();
           Console.WriteLine("Choose between the two sorting strategies:");
           Console.WriteLine("\ta) - Bubble Sort");
           Console.WriteLine("\tb) - Quick Sort");
           Console.WriteLine();
           Console.Write("Your option: ");

          
           response = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            

           Console.WriteLine();

           switch (response.ToString().ToLower())
           {
               case "a":
                  _strategy = new BubbleSort();
                   _strategy.Implementation(userInput);
                   break;
               case "b":
                   _strategy = new QuickSort();
                   _strategy.Implementation(userInput);
                   break;
               default:
                   Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer. Please enter a valid option.");
                   response = '\0';
                   break;
           }

        } while (response == '\0');
        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
     }
  }
}
```

> **IStrategy interface**

```
public interface IStrategy
{
   void Implementation(string useInput);
}
```

> **BubbleSort class**

```
class BubbleSort : IStrategy
{
   public void Implementation(string userInput)
   {
      string temp;
      string[] stringArray = userInput.Trim().Split(' ');
      for (int x = 1; x < stringArray.Length; x++)
      {
          for (int y = 0; y < stringArray.Length - 1; y++)
          {
             if (String.Compare(stringArray[y], stringArray[y + 1], comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0)
             {
                temp = stringArray[y];
                stringArray[y] = stringArray[y + 1];
                stringArray[y + 1] = temp;
             }
          }
      }

      Console.Write("Bubble Sort: ");

      int i = 1;
      foreach (string uinput in stringArray)
      {
         if (i == stringArray.Length)
             Console.Write(uinput);
         else
             Console.Write(uinput + ", ");
             i++;
      }
  }
}
```

> **QuickSort class**

```
class QuickSort : IStrategy
{
   public void Implementation(string userInput)
   {
      string[] stringArray = userInput.Trim().Split(' ');
      Quick_Sort(stringArray, 0, stringArray.Length - 1);

     Console.Write("Quick Sort: ");

     int i = 1;
     foreach (string uinput in stringArray)
     {
        if (i == stringArray.Length)
            Console.Write(uinput);
         else
            Console.Write(uinput + ", ");
        i++;
     }
  }

  static void Quick_Sort(string[] userInput, int left, int right)
  {
     if (left < right)
     {
        int pivot = Partition(userInput, left, right);

        if (pivot > 1)
        {
            Quick_Sort(userInput, left, pivot - 1);
        }
        if (pivot + 1 < right)
        {
            Quick_Sort(userInput, pivot + 1, right);
        }
     }
  }

  private static int Partition(string[] arr, int left, int right)
  {
     string pivot = arr[left];
     while (true)
     {
       int comparison = String.Compare(arr[left], pivot, comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
       while (String.Compare(arr[left], pivot, comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0 && left < right)
       {
           left++;
       }

       while (String.Compare(arr[right], pivot, comparisonType: StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > 0 && right > 0)
       {
           right--;
       }

       if (left < right)
       {
          if (arr[left] == arr[right]) return right;

          string temp = arr[left];
          arr[left] = arr[right];
          arr[right] = temp;
       }
       else
       {
          return right;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Bubble Sort

[image]

Quick Sort

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My answers assume you are trying to use the Strategy pattern to implement various sort methods.

Below are some coding tips that might be helpful:

**Converting string data to a string array**

As mention by @00110001, you can use the String.Split method to convert a string to an array of strings.  In my example, I am passing in two parameters.  The first determines what to delimited on, the second will remove any empty entries.

Example:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };
string[] strInputArray = userInput.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

**Code Organization:**

In this instance, you should not place classes inside other classes.  They are not needed and the way you implement them makes your code very hard to read.  I would suggest re-organizing the code as the follows example shows:

Example:

```
namespace SortStrategyPattern
{
    public interface ISortStrategy
    {
    }

    public class BubbleSort : ISortStrategy
    {
    }

    public class QuickSort : ISortStrategy
    {
    }

    public class SortContext : ISortStrategy
    {
    }

    class Program
    {
    }
}
```

**Encapsulate like functionality**

You should only include logic that accomplishes a certain task in your classes.  Mixing functionality just complicate things.  Example your Context class should only contain logic that deal with storing a certain sorting strategy.

Example:

```
public class SortContext : ISortStrategy
{
    private ISortStrategy _strategy;

    private SortContext() { }

    public SortContext(ISortStrategy strategy)
    {
        _strategy = strategy;
    }

    public void SetStrategy(ISortStrategy strategy)
    {
        _strategy = strategy;
    }

    public string[] Sort(string[] data)
    {
        return _strategy.Sort(data);
    }
}
```

The logic that handles the user input and display the results should be place in the Program class Main method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] delimiterChars = { ' ' };
    string userInput = "", sortOpt="";


    do
    {
        // Retrieve a list of strings from the user.  Each string is separated by one or more spaces.
        Console.Write("Enter a list of strings: ");
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        // Terminate loop if blank/empty string is passed
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInput))
            break;


        // Split user input into a series of strings.  Assuming empty entries are not allowed.
        // Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split
        string[] strInputArray = userInput.Split(delimiterChars, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


        // Inquire sort method to use
        Console.WriteLine("Choose between the two sorting strategies:");
        Console.WriteLine("\ta) - Bubble Sort");
        Console.WriteLine("\tb) - Quick Sort");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Your option: ");
        sortOpt = Console.ReadLine();


        // Determine the sort method
        SortContext context = null;
        switch ( sortOpt.Trim() )
        {
            case "a":
                Console.WriteLine("\nPerforming Bubble Sort");
                context = new SortContext(new BubbleSort());
                break;

            case "b":
                Console.WriteLine("\nPerforming Quick Sort");
                context = new SortContext(new QuickSort());
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid answer. Please enter a valid option.");
                continue;
        }


        string[] resultArray = context.Sort(strInputArray);
        foreach (string str in resultArray)
            Console.WriteLine(str);

    } while (true);



    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...."); Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you use method `userInput.ToCharArray();` to separate what user inputs to the application.

You should use `Split` method, where you can specify which character to split by. So it look like: `userInput.Split(' ');`

Also, on how to make it better. You split the user input in a sorting algorithm - that's messing up repsonsibilities - sorting algorithm should take care only of sorting, not preparing input. That way, you also duplicate the code to split the string.

Sorting methods should accept `string[]` (array of strings) to sort.

So, changes should be done like that:

Change declaration: `public static string[] userInput;` (also, IMO that should just regular variable..)

`userInput = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');` - here we prepare our input

And lastly - change method declarations:

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    object Implementation(string[] userInput);
}
```

Also you do not need return type on that method, as you do not return any variable, just constant 0, which is not used anywhere. So yuo can even more simplify:

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    void Implementation(string[] userInput);
}
```